# Getting milliseconds from JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, date, milliseconds, jspinner

I'm trying to extract milliseconds between actual time and the time defined by the `JSpinner` control (`spnTimer`). The spinner format is: hh:mm:ss.
Since I'm pretty new to Java, I'm not able to get the desired result.
When I tried to convert spinner time in a string, I'm getting time back in 1970.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
String s = spnTimer.getValue().toString();
System.out.println("spinner time: "+ s);
```

Result:

```
spinner time: Thu Jan 01 09:43:19 CET 1970
```

Comment: Hi! May we ask for some more context code? Looking at the API is not clear what values are present in the spinner, if you get that time as a default.

Answer (score 0):

The spinner is returning the "epoch" value. The epoch traditionally corresponds to 0 hours, 0 minutes, and 0 seconds (00:00:00) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) on a specific date, which varies from system to system and the epoch value measures seconds since then.
Try the following code, i bet it will work

```
Date spinnerValue = (Date) spinner.getValue();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMM/dd");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date actualDate = sdf2.parse(sdf1.format(new Date()) + " " + sdf.format(spinnerValue), new ParsePosition(0));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks.
But, how to get difference in milliseconds?

Comment: Check if Date.getTime() - actualDate.getTime() makes it :)

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.